# Problem adding the Mono repository to a Red Hat 7 server

Tags: mono

Having a problem importing the rpmkeys for mono on a Red Hat 7 server(Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)).

I'm getting the error below:

```
[root@hostname ~]# rpmkeys --import "http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3fa7e0328081bff6a14da29aa6a19b38d3d831ef"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pool.sks-keyservers.net.lehigh.edu; Name or service not known
error: http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3fa7e0328081bff6a14da29aa6a19b38d3d831ef: import read failed(2).
```

Any ideas on what might cause this...

Comment: where did you get the instructions to import that key from pool.sks-keyservers.net?

Answer (score 0):

Running the commands below seems to have resolved the problem

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```